# LinearModelFit for ANCOVA Issues with Fitted Model & Plot with Bonferroni F-value corrections

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting

In attempting to modify the example for generating an [ANCOVA model](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/newin7/content/StatisticalModelAnalysis/ComputeAndVisualizeResultsForAnANCOVAModel.html) for my data (data3), which is for purposes of illustration the first 20 and the last 20 records of a larger dataset.  Here, I seek to compare two rather than four groups given in the example, I have encountered several issues that I do not understand and that leave me wondering if my modifications are correct.  Unlike the example that uses generated data for 4 treatments, I am comparing two measurements (standard length and head length) from two different species (treatments/groups).  These data are in mm.

```
data3 = {{1, 220.5, 107.2}, {1, 150.8, 70.6}, {1, 74.52, 33.71}, {1, 76.3, 
        35.1}, {1, 74.59, 34.52}, {1, 95.77, 45.32}, {1, 74.52, 33.71}, {1, 
        96.66, 44.32}, {1, 104.1, 49.7}, {1, 89., 41.1}, {1, 79.1, 
        38.1}, {1, 76.46, 33.83}, {1, 228.5, 103.7}, {1, 170.2, 81.8}, {1, 
        218.5, 99.5}, {1, 238., 105.8}, {1, 243.9, 112.}, {1, 65.67, 
        27.39}, {1, 103.81, 45.63}, {1, 95.29, 41.8}, {2, 111.27, 
        51.77}, {2, 174.05, 82.05}, {2, 166.15, 80.3}, {2, 51.74, 
        23.37}, {2, 196.4, 89.91}, {2, 96.58, 43.05}, {2, 168.82, 
        72.47}, {2, 181.95, 83.14}, {2, 132.11, 61.34}, {2, 105.82, 
        46.6}, {2, 112.36, 54.53}, {2, 72.19, 31.}, {2, 62.14, 28.89}, {2, 
        64.81, 26.84}, {2, 47.11, 22.27}, {2, 95.45, 49.19}, {2, 208.49, 
        97.}, {2, 116.02, 53.84}, {2, 105., 51.6}, {2, 106.6, 48.3}}
```

Following the example, I then execute the following modification:

```
 lm = LinearModelFit[data3, {species, sl}, {species, sl}, 
  NominalVariables -> species];
  Grid[{{lm["ANOVATable"]}, {Show[ListPlot[Drop[
  GatherBy[Sort[data3], First], None, None, 1], 
  PlotRange -> {{0, Max[data2[[All, 2]]]}, {0, 
    Max[data2[[All, 3]]]}}], 
  Plot[Evaluate[Map[lm[#, t] &, groups3]], {t, 0, 250}]]}, {lm}}]
```

I get the ANOVATable, with some suspicious P-values, followed by the plot, which seems to be missing the calulated least square fit line for either species, and a fitted model that I do not understand that reads:

FittedModel[ -1.94155 + 0.463712 SL - 0.294817 DiscreteIndicator[species,1,(1,2)]

Why is the plot of the least-squares line of best fit missing?  I have substituted 250 for the range of "t", since the highest possible value of SL is about 250, but this interpretation may be at odds with the example.

If I am interpreting the fitted model output correctly, the result can be interpreted as
the HL (data3[[All,3]] =  the y-intercept (HL= -1.94155) + the slope (0.463712 *SL) - the adjusted mean resulting from the variance attributable to being different species (0.294817) given equal slopes for the two species.  However, I am confused by the meaning of DiscreteIndicator[species,1,(1,2)], which I suspect, simply reflects the fact that species in the first column of data3 is regarded as the dummy variable.  Is this interpretation correct?

The very small P-values suggest that the adjusted means are not the same, even though from the plot (even of this small amount of data) the two species appear to be virtually identical with respect to these variables.  Is my suspicion that the adjusted means are NOT significantly different justified?

Likewise, I am unsure how to obtain the critical Bonferroni or Sheffe F-Values to account for Type 1 Error for multiple comparisons from these results, when after a test for homogenetity of regression slopes prove that the slopes of different groups are statistically the same as they are for this contrast.

I have many such comparisons to make for other variables against SL and am eager to determine if my modification of the example code is correct so that these results can be extended for multiple comparisons (about 40) for which it seems prudent to use suitably corrected F-Values to compute the probability that the adjusted means are in fact different when the slopes are not.

Can anyone set me straight as to how to compute this ANCOVA properly and to extend it with a Bonferroni or Sheffe correction?  Thanks.

Comment: Your code has some issues: data2 and groups3 are undefined.

Comment: Yes, Sloppy cutting and pasting.  Data2 =Data3[[All,2;;3]; group3 left out which is just {"species 1", "species 2" Sorry for that.

Answer (score 6):

Your model fit and ANOVA table are

```
lm = LinearModelFit[data3, {species, sl}, {species, sl}, NominalVariables -> species];
lm["ANOVATable"]
```

[image: ANOVA Table]

The P-value of 9.08206 x 10^-7 looks "suspicious" but that's because that P-value isn't what you think it is.  *Mathematica* is using what is called (in SAS lingo) "Type I Sums of Squares" or "Sequential sum of squares".  This is the sum of squares associated with species unadjusted for the covariate (`sl` = standard length). (And more generally sequential sums of squares are "adjusted for terms preceding it and unadjusted for terms following it".)

You can get an appropriate P-value for testing whether the intercepts for both species are identical by simply changing `{species, sl}, {species, sl}` to  `{sl, species}, {species, sl}`.

```
lm = LinearModelFit[data3, {sl, species}, {species, sl}, NominalVariables -> species]
lm["ANOVATable"]
```

[image: ANOVA table with correct P-values for species equivalence]

Does that sound crazy?  Yes, it does.  I love *Mathematica* but it has a long ways to go before I would use it for analysis of variance or analysis of covariance.

**Addition**

If you need to do a lot of multiple comparisons and want to use various adjustments (such as Tukey, Bonferroni, etc.), you should use R or SAS rather than *Mathematica*.  But if you're just interested in all possible pairwise comparisons from a simple ANCOVA, here's one (convoluted) way to do it.

Create some data.

```
groups = {"control", "treatment 1", "treatment 2", "treatment 3"};

data = BlockRandom[SeedRandom[123];
   Block[{vals, times, rand}, vals = RandomChoice[groups, 100];
    times = RandomInteger[10, 100];
    rand = RandomReal[1, 100];
    Transpose[{vals, times, (vals /. 
         Thread[Rule[groups, {.16, .34, .57, 1.1}]]) - .05 times + rand}]]];
```

Fit the model and get estimates of parameters.

```
lm = LinearModelFit[data, {treatment, time}, {treatment, time}, 
  NominalVariables -> treatment, IncludeConstantBasis -> False]
estimates = lm["BestFitParameters"];
cov = lm["CovarianceMatrix"];
```

Now find all possible differences in the treatments (i.e., the intercepts of a simple linear model).

```
(* Number of treatments *)
t = Length[groups]; 

(* Degrees of freedom for error *)
df = lm["ANOVATableDegreesOfFreedom"][[Length[ lm["ANOVATableDegreesOfFreedom"]] - 1]]
(* 95 *)

(* Indices of all possible pairwise comparisons *)
comparisons = Select[Sort[#] & /@ Tuples[Range[t], {2}], #[[1]] < #[[2]] &] // DeleteDuplicates
(* {{1,2},{1,3},{1,4},{2,3},{2,4},{3,4}} *)

(* Differences and standard errors of differences *)
diffs = estimates[[#[[1]]]] - estimates[[#[[2]]]] & /@ comparisons
(* {-0.070739, -0.425142, -0.814842, -0.354403, -0.744103, -0.389699} *)

seDiffs = Sqrt[cov[[#[[1]], #[[1]]]] + cov[[#[[2]], #[[2]]]] - 
     2 cov[[#[[1]], #[[2]]]]] & /@ comparisons
(* {0.0883031, 0.089601, 0.0895971, 0.0828474, 0.0879348, 0.0891328} *)
```

Now put together the pieces to determine the Bonferroni adjusted P-values and confidence limits for the pairwise differences:

```
tValues = (estimates[[#[[1]]]] - estimates[[#[[2]]]])/
    Sqrt[cov[[#[[1]], #[[1]]]] + cov[[#[[2]], #[[2]]]] - 
      2 cov[[#[[1]], #[[2]]]]] & /@ comparisons
(* {-0.801093, -4.74484, -9.09451, -4.27779, -8.46198, -4.37212} *)

Pvalues = 2*CDF[StudentTDistribution[df], -Abs[#]] & /@ tValues
(* {0.425077, 7.34947*10^-6, 1.42412*10^-14, 0.0000449881,  3.17124*10^-13, 0.0000314736} *)

α = 0.05/Length[comparisons]
(* 0.00833333 *)

confLimits = Transpose[{diffs - InverseCDF[StudentTDistribution[95], 1 - α/2] seDiffs,
   diffs + InverseCDF[StudentTDistribution[95], 1 - α/2] seDiffs}]
(* {{-0.308683, 0.167205}, {-0.666584, -0.183701}, {-1.05627, 0.573411}, 
    {-0.577646, -0.131161}, {-0.981054, -0.507151}, {-0.629879, -0.14952}} *)
```

**Second addition**

With the above data one can also fit separate intercepts and separate slopes with `LinearModelFit`:

```
lm = LinearModelFit[data, {treatment, treatment*time}, {treatment, time}, 
  NominalVariables -> treatment, IncludeConstantBasis -> False];
lm["ParameterTable"]
```

[image: Parameter table]

**Third addition**

If you want to get a test for equal slopes:

```
lm = LinearModelFit[data, {treatment, x, treatment*x}, {treatment, x},
    NominalVariables -> treatment];
lm["ANOVATable"]
```

[image: ANOVA table with test for equal slopes]

So the P-value for testing equal slopes is 0.832571.  (I would still suggest using R or SAS for anything beyond a basic ANOVA as with *Mathematica* while you can get all of the right tests, there is a lot of handwork which can easily result in coding errors.)

Comment: Yes, but I have a hammer (Mathematica) and everything looks like a nail.  I find the logic behind how the parameters in Linear Model Fit are to be structured difficult to grasp.  Thanks for the insight.  Any suggestions with regard to the Bonferroni error correction?

Comment: This might be helpful:  http://www.utstat.utoronto.ca/reid/sta442f/2009/typeSS.pdf for the sum of squares definitions.  About adjustments for multiple comparisons:  just because one can adjust, that doesn't mean one should.  But if I have time tomorrow, I'll include something about multiple comparisons.

Comment: Yes, the pdf was useful.  Thank you. Comments on multiple comparisons would be even more so, since there are quite a few species in the genus I'm working on.

Comment: As a statistician I have to ask:  If you have quite a few species, would you not want to have potentially different coefficients for standard length for each species?  (Especially if you have plenty of data.)  You already have different intercepts for each species.  Why not different slopes for each species?  And, in addition, is it reasonable to assume the error variance is identical for all species?

Comment: Yes, some of the slopes are different among the species.  My understanding is that one can not use ANCOVA when a test of homogeneity of slopes is rejected.  I am measuring all species in the same way, but beyond that there is no way to insure that error variance is identical.  The results suggest that the error variance is approximately equal, at least for the measures I have taken so far.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way I know to set up any design that assure equivalent random variation, since all one has is the measures of the organisms themselves, so the only tests I can make are to compare slopes and, if equal, look at the adusted means for the different species determine if there appears to be is a "species effect".

Comment: It is my understanding the Johnson - Neymann technique could be used to compare those portions of the domain, where the slopes to appear identical, but I have yet to figure out how to do this.  Would be eager to learn about other possible approaches.

Comment: Thank you for the informative additional comments.  All I have is "species effect", and the underlying assumption that I have correctly identified the species (in this case one is new and presently can only differentiated by some of the measures and counts).  There is no possibility of a "control" as within an experimental design.  Effectively, nature has done the experiment and I am left to interpret the measured differences, not an ideal situation for statistical design to assure randomness, homogeneity, etc.  Life as a taxonomist interested in morphometrics is cruel in this respect.

Comment: Should have mentioned "and CODE".  Thank you.  Although I have passing familiarity with R and do not have access to SAS (too expensive & I'm retired), I find Mathematica useful, since it forces me to understand the methods and limitations in detail, the quixotic syntax that can be a major obstacle for using it for this purpose notwithstanding.

Comment: (1) "Can not use ANCOVA when a test of homogeneity of slopes is rejected." Baloney!  Nothing wrong with allowing for different slopes.  (2) No need to "assure equivalent random variation".  Software these days allows one to account for that.  Well, software other than *Mathematica*.  (3) The Johnson-Neyman technique was introduced in 1936 when computers weren't even around.  Time to get out of the hypothesis-testing/P-value mode.  (4) Experimental designs don't always need a control.  (5) No need and there should be no expectation of homogeneity with Mother Nature.  (6) I'm retired, too.

Comment: (1) This seems in direct contradiction to Huitema (1980) (see p. 47 summary, pp. 102-103 regarding regression slopes and computations therein.

Comment: Not to be argumentative here, since I've been struggling with statistics since I was first introduced to the concepts.  However, its worth noting that Gauss didn't have a computer to calculate least squares either, but his concept remain valid.   Johnson-Neyman was rewritten in Mathematica but I don't understand the code and now can no longer locate it on the internet.

Comment: Arguments are good - especially when it ends up with one of us having an "aha!" moment.  Unfortunately I don't have access to Huitema (1980).

Comment: 3) I've heard this before, but don't fully understand the comment. 
 Isn't statistics based on probability and expectation based on assumed distributions of variates and hence the need for some standards regarding what is to be regarded as "significant deviation from expected"?  If there are to be no "hypothesis tests", what is statistics left with?  I am only seeking to demonstrate whether or not there are potentially biologically/statistically meaningful differences.  From your comments, it's unclear to me how one would otherwise differentiate "trivial" from "significant" differences.

Comment: To quote Huitema, p. 47 "The interpretation of ANCOVA and associated adjusted means relies very heavily on the assumption of homogenous regression slopes for various treatment groups.  If the assumption is not met, ANCOVA F test and the adjustment process can lead to highly misleading results.  For this reason the homogeneity of slopes test should be carried out whenever ANCOVA is employed."   His subsequent discussion is more involved (pp. 101-103) but centers on what happens to adjusted means when slopes are not the same.  Seems like a convincing argument to me.

Comment: I've added code to the answer which shows how to fit separate slopes for each treatment.  This was my point about if a test of homogeneity is rejected.  Wouldn't the next step be to estimate the heterogeneity?  I would start with assuming heterogeneity in slopes and intercepts (especially if there was plenty of data) and then collapsing to a single slope if that appeared plausible.

Comment: I am in complete agreement with what Huitema states.  One wouldn't continue with a single slope when it wasn't warranted.  So therefore one would fit separate slopes.  What one would stop is using ANCOVA with a single slope.

Comment: Thank you for the second addition. Can we go to chat?

Comment: That would be good.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134441/discussion-between-jimb-and-stuart-poss).